# How to define a macro in a header file from the makefile

Tags: c++, macros, makefile

I have written my own header file for checking assertions myassert.h, similar to the assert.h header and I include this in another file, say project_file.h.  I also have the NDEBUG macro which when defined before the inclusion of myassert.h, disables the checking of the assertions.
However, I dont want to turn off the assertion checking by defining NDEBUG at the beginning of project_file.h. Instead I want to have a flag in the makefile so that during compilation, the user can set the flag that will automatically disable/enable the assertions checking feature. 
The file project_file.h is just one file in a huge project. Can anyone please tell me how to do this? I have checked the other answers but I did not quite understand how to make it work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that what you want is easy to do with CMake, and easy to manage for the user.

Comment: CMake is a more advanced tool for cross-platform compilation, which isn't really what the poster wants to know. CMake is a very powerful tool, and yes it is simple to add options that turn into preprocessor definitions, but the poster would a.) have to learn CMake, and b.) would not be aware of the simple command-line syntax that is available to every build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a preprocessor definition. You should pass `-DNDEBUG` to the gcc options.

For more information about the `-D` option: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html

There are two ways to use `-D`: `-D name`, `-D name=definition`.

Then in your code you would use:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
    // ...
#endif
```

or

```
#if NDEBUG!=0
    // ...
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,the -D option worked, except the fact that there doesn't have to be any space between D and the name of the macro